# ggplot2: adjusting the number of points on a line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to lower the number of points on the lines on my plot.

For example,

```
date <- c("2017-04-15","2017-04-16","2017-04-17","2017-04-18","2017-04-19","2017-04-20","2017-04-21")
x <- c(1,3,3,4,3,5,2)

df <- data.frame(date,x)
```

Rather than having a point located at every vertex. I would like one located at every other vertex. The first, third, fifth and seventh vertex would have points while the others would not.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date,x,group=1)) +
  geom_line(size=.4) + 
  geom_point(size=.7)
```

This seems simple enough, but I have been unable to find any information on how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean points on the axis, as in the answer by @username, or do you mean the points on your graph as in the geom_points?

Comment: I mean the points on the graph, `geom_points`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_x_date` to scale your x axis dates

```
date <- c("2017-04-15","2017-04-16","2017-04-17","2017-04-18","2017-04-19","2017-04-20","2017-04-21")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,3,5,2)

#Convert date to DATE format using as.Date()
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(date),x)

ggplot(df, aes(date,x,group=1)) +
  geom_line(size=.4) + 
  geom_point(size=.7) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 day", date_labels = "%d-%b") #using Scale_x_date to change the spacing and label format for display
```